# Evaluate conditions before custom actions

Tags: .net, visual-studio, wix, windows-installer, installation

I have this action under `InstallUISequence`:

```
<Custom Action="WarnIfOutlookNotInstalled" Sequence="1"><![CDATA[NOT Installed]]></Custom>
```

I also have this condition:

```
<PropertyRef Id="NETFRAMEWORK45"/>
<Condition Message="This product requires .NET Framework 4.5 or later."><![CDATA[Installed OR NETFRAMEWORK45]]></Condition>
```

The custom action named `WarnIfOutlookNotInstalled` is defined in a custom action DLL which targets .NET 4.0. The problem I have is that, when I run my MSI, it tries to run the `WarnIfOutlookNotInstalled` custom action before trying to evaluate my above `Condition`. I need this to be the other way, where it must evaluate the condition before the custom action, because if .NET 4 is not installed, it fails completely, and presents the user with my fatal error screen which says that, "The installer was interrupted before it could be installed. You need to restart the installer to try again." How can I get around this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A custom actions gets executed at a [certain step during the installation](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/standard-actions.html), depending on where you schedule it.

In your case, you need to schedule the custom action to be executed after the standard action "LaunchConditions". By adding something like this in < InstalUISequence >:

```
  <Custom Action="WarnIfOutlookNotInstalled" After="LaunchConditions"><![CDATA[NOT Installed]]></Custom>
```

Comment: Multzumesc, frate :) A mers.